# How to perform a conditional upsert in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am providing a simple example in order to describe what I am looking for.

I have a collection holding the oldest people in a city.
It currently looks like this:

```
{ "name" : "Arthur", "city" : "New York", "age" : 42}
{ "name" : "Arthur", "city" : "London",   "age" : 42}
{ "name" : "Berta",  "city" : "New York", "age" : 42}
```

I have created the following index:

```
db.people.createIndex( { name:1, city:1 }, { unique: true} )
```

I want to perform an upsert based on the following condition:

1. if there is no such Person for "name" and "city", insert it
2. if there is a Person for "name" and "city", update "age" to the greater

So if I perform the upsert with

```
{ "name" : "Arthur", "city" : "New York", "age" : 43}
```

The collection would look like that afterwards:

```
{ "name" : "Arthur", "city" : "New York", "age" : 43}
{ "name" : "Arthur", "city" : "London",   "age" : 42}
{ "name" : "Berta",  "city" : "New York", "age" : 42}
```

Could please anybody show me the upsert command for the mongo shell?

Comment: What do you mean by "update age to greater"? if someone to try to update age less than existing record, shouldn't be updated?

Comment: I want updates only if there is an older person in the same city. For example another Arthur in New York of age 42 (or less) would not make it into the db. Another Arthur in New York of age 43 (or greater) would make into the db (update). Ceaser would be inserted anyways, since there is no Ceasar so far. Sorry if I was not clear enough.

Comment: Understood, Please see my updated solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do so using following query

```
db.col.update(
{ "name" : "Arthur", "city" : "New York", age: {$lte: 43}},
{ "name" : "Arthur", "city" : "New York", "age":43},
{upsert: true})
```

See `{upset: true}`, this option makes sure that if there is existing record, just update it otherwise insert new document.

You can get more information at [MongoDB Website](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db-collection-update)

Comment: Thank you Saleem. Unbelievably simple. I have read the mongodb docs before I posted my question but did not get it... Sometimes examples help a lot more.

Comment: But wait, if there is an existing row with the same name and city, but age: 44, the query will not match anything and you will add a new row. Then, you'll have two rows with the same name and city but different ages, right?

Comment: i think it belongs to your index field unique from collection (name, city, age) vs (name, age)